# Project Euler 19: Counting Sundays, Java

Tags: java, calendar, dayofweek

I'm using the Calendar API of Java to calculate the total number of sundays which fall on the first day of every month.
The Following code gives me 1 extra days for the specified starting date and ending date of date format (Year/Month/Date). 1900/01/01 to 1910/01/01

Input format of the code is : 
1<=Testcases<=10
Starting Date
Ending Date

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
public class ProjectEuler19 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int testCases = scanner.nextInt();
    do{
     int sundays = 0;
     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     int monthStart,dateStart,monthEnd,dateEnd;
     int yearStart,yearEnd;
     yearStart = scanner.nextInt();
     monthStart = scanner.nextInt();
     dateStart = scanner.nextInt();
     yearEnd = scanner.nextInt();
     monthEnd = scanner.nextInt();
     dateEnd = scanner.nextInt();
     String[] getDayOfWeek = new String[]{
        "MONDAY",
        "TUESDAY",
        "WEDNESDAY",
        "THURSDAY",
        "FRIDAY",
        "SATURDAY",
        "SUNDAY"
     };
        for(int y = yearStart; y<=yearEnd; y++) {
                for(int m = monthStart; m<=12; m++) {
                        c.set(y,m-1,1);
                        if(String.valueOf(getDayOfWeek[c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1]).equals(String.valueOf(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY))) {
                            sundays++;
                        }
                        if(m > monthEnd && y == yearEnd)
                            break;
                }
        }
        System.out.println(sundays);
       testCases--;
    }while(testCases != 0 && testCases>=1 && testCases<=100);

  }
}
```

And the sample out put is :

```
2
1900 1 1
1910 1 1
17
2000 1 1
2020 1 1
36
```

According the calendar the number of sundays between 1900 and 1910 are 18 and the number of sundays between 2000 and 2010 are 35.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually counting the number of Mondays. Calendar.SUNDAY is the first week day constant, and has value 1.

Why not compare c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) with Calendar.SUNDAY directly?